# How does a parameter become a function call in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I often like to say that JS is not my home language and that's led me to this question.

```
import Dropzone from "dropzone";

let myDropzone = Dropzone({
  paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  maxFilesize: 2, // MB
  accept: function(file, done) {
    if (file.name == "justinbieber.jpg") {
      done("Naha, you don't.");
    }
    else { done(); }
  }
});
```

The preceding code is from Dropzone website about their great file upload tool.

The else done() confuses me. How would you know that's a function if you were calling this? Done sports appears to be a parameter to me. If I'm using a good IDE, would I be directed as such? If not  how do I know?

Comment: Well, you would know by reading the documentation, I would hope. Otherwise, you could always use the `typeof` operator on it to find out `if (typeof done === 'function') { done(); }`. The title question is a bit odd; it becomes a function call when you invoke it as a function call, using parentheses. Functions are variables just like any other.

Comment: the documentation for the `accept` property passed to `Dropzone` function would specify that `accept` is a function that takes a `file` as the first argument, and a callback function as the second - and (perhaps internally?) the accept function is called with the correct arguments - do you ever call that `accept` method or is it purely an internal method for `Dropzone` to use when required?

Comment: If you were using TypeScript or JSDocs, you would get an error in your IDE

Comment: @Samathingamajig - if I had 4 wheels and an engine I'd be a car - what's your point

Comment: @Bravo what do you mean?

Comment: OP isn't using TypeScript or JSDocs, and who knows if his IDE even would show an error (not all IDE's are created equal) so your comment doesn't help the question at all

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, every function is an object, and can be used just like an object.

You can call

```
console.log(typeof done)
```

to see that the parameter is a function.

Answer (score 0):

JS uses duck typing, which in this case means that the value of `done` is checked just before trying to call it. If it's callable, everything is good. If not, an error is thrown *at runtime*.

As to whether your IDE will tell you about this, that will depend on how good your IDE is at doing static typechecks, but I'd assume it's not a common feature. Duck typing is very permissive, making it generally difficult to determine whether some code will throw an error without running it.